# execute a function before dataTable.net draws table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using [dataTable.net](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin to draw a table on my html page, It is working fine. I want to execute a function say `xyz()` which contains a ajax call (ajax call also executing as I want). Before drawing the table I want to execute `xyz()` function, but it is first drawing table and then executing the function.
I am calling `xyz()` as

```
    $(function () {
    xyz();

    // dataTable.net code.

    });

    xyz()
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
          // some code
       }); 
    }
```

Actually, I am fetching some data from server, and trying to render it to the dataTable.net 
but dataTable.net is drawing table first and after the ajax call is getting complete, though I am calling ajax before dataTable.net.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think JavaScript is not waiting for the ajax to complete means getting back with some data, it is just going on. I think, it is just executing the ajax function and moving further. 
For now I managed it by drawing dataTable in ajax's success, If any one can improve it, please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      xyz();
        $('Your Div ID').load(function() {
           // // dataTable.net code.
         });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but its not working. it is giving error -  SyntaxError: invalid label

Comment: pls add any div id at place of Your Div ID.

Answer (score 0):

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks, use callback "fnInitComplete"

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
          //check first draw
            if (json.draw == 1) {
                xyz(); //call your function here
            }
        }
    });
});
```